# Why doesn't this code correctly compute sin(x)?

Tags: c++, math, trigonometry

I am about to lose my mind. I have been staring at this for hours, and I cannot figure out what is wrong. When I enter a value of "1", I just get that the sum is 1, meaning that it has only gone this through the iteration once, but I don't know why seeing that the abs(term) should be greater than "lesser".

I am trying to calculate sin(x) given the user inputs x.

```
double sum = 0.0;
double term = 0.0;
double n = 1.0;
double x = 0.0;
double lesser = 1.0e-15;


while (true)
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter radian value of x:";
    std::cin >> x;
    if (x == 999)
        return 0;

    term = x;
    sum = 0.0;
    n = 1.0;

    while (abs (term) >= lesser)
    {
        sum = sum + term;
        n = n + 1.0;
        term = -term * (x/n);
        n = n + 1.0;
        term = term * (x/n);

    }
    std::cout << "\nApproximation for sin(0) is is: " << sum;
}


return 0;
```

Comment: I recommend reading [How to Debug Small Programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) to get a better idea of how to debug this.

Comment: This program works correctly for me if I put `#include <iostream>\n#include <cmath>\nint main()\n{` at the top, `}` at the bottom, and change `abs` to `std::abs`.  I conclude from this that the problem is with the definition of `abs`.  Where is that coming from?

Comment: @dionadar Where do you get that from?

Comment: @Paulpro Whoops, my bad

Comment: @Zack That helps, but it's still no quite correct. If I enter a value like 10, it loops infinitely. Do I need to declare absolute as double abs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `std::abs` function works on integral types. You probably should be using `std::fabs`:

```
while (fabs (term) >= lesser) {
   ...
}
```

There may be other errors in the code, but this one will probably cause the loop to exit early because `abs` will round values in the range (0, 1) down to 0. `fabs` avoids this.

Alternatively, use the `<cmath>` header instead of the `<math.h>` header, or explicitly call `std::abs`. `<cmath>` exports overloads of `abs` for floating-point values.

Hope this helps!

Comment: `#include <cmath>` overloads `std::abs` to correctly handle types `int`, `long`, `long long`, `float`, `double`, and `long double`.  But `#include <math.h>` does not.

Answer (score 0):

Use `fabs`, not `abs`. `abs` is for integers and is killing the fractional part of your number. Or you can use `std::abs`